# Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, indentation

I can't seem to figure out what's going on here. When I compile I get the *does not match* error.

It gives me the error about indentation mismatch on the line with `bgB = 0;`

```
def calcBG(ftemp):
"This calculates the color value for the background"
variance = ftemp - justRight;   # Calculate the variance
adj = calcColorAdj(variance);   # Scale it to 8 bit int
bgList = [0,0,0]                # initialize the color array
if(variance < 0):         
    bgR = 0;                    # too cold, no red         bgB = adj;                  # green and blue slide equally with adj         bgG = 255 - adj;     elif(variance == 0):            # perfect, all on green         bgR = 0;         bgB = 0;         bgG = 255;     elif(variance > 0):             # too hot - no blue
    bgB = 0;
    bgR = adj;                  # red and green slide equally with Adj
    bgG = 255 - adj;
```

so after updating the code with what @Downshift suggested and adding a few elifs i got the same thing

`def calcBG(ftemp):
    "This calculates the color value for the background"
    variance = ftemp - justRight;   # Calculate the variance
    adj = calcColorAdj(variance);   # Scale it to 8 bit int
    bgList = [0,0,0]                # initialize the color array
    if(variance < 0):

        bgR = 0;                    # too cold, no red

        bgB = adj;                  # green and blue slide equally with adj

        bgG = 255 - adj;

    elif(variance == 0):            # perfect, all on green

        bgR = 0;

        bgB = 0;

        bgG = 255;

    elif(variance > 0):             # too hot - no blue
        bgB = 0;
        bgR = adj;                  # red and green slide equally with Adj
        bgG = 255 - adj;`

ALSO: if someone could point out/explain to me exactly what i'm failing at that'd be great. because i can't seem to find my issue in this second portion. which is the same issue as the first.

Comment: no `;` in python, and indent after `def ...:`

Comment: @JulienBernu actually it is allowed to use semicolons there

Comment: If you're using Python 2, you may be mixing spaces and tabs. That's an error all by itself in Python 3. You might try running Python with the `-t` flag (which will make mixed whitespace give a warning) or `-tt` (which will make it an error).

Comment: Source view confirms you've mixed tabs and spaces. Stop doing that.

Comment: Running your code exactly as you've put it in the question runs fine, I don't get any formatting/indention or any errors, so it's not clear where the problem is. Are you running your code in an IDE or some kind of specialized code editor/formatter? As others mention, just be consistent with spacing, use the same number of spaces (usually 4 spaces per indent) OR one Tab indent, but the PEP-008 recommends just use all spaces, look at this here: [Code lay-out](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id16). And as stated above, whichever you choose, tabs or spaces, only use one NOT both.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the interpreter tells you your indentation levels are not consistent. Be sure to indent after first line of method definitions and `if` statements, With no changes to your code other than fixing indents:

```
def calcBG(ftemp):
    """This calculates the color value for the background"""
    variance = ftemp - justRight;   # Calculate the variance
    adj = calcColorAdj(variance);   # Scale it to 8 bit int
    bgList = [0,0,0]                # initialize the color array
    if(variance < 0):         
        bgR = 0;                    # too cold, no red         bgB = adj;                  # green and blue slide equally with adj         bgG = 255 - adj;     elif(variance == 0):            # perfect, all on green         bgR = 0;         bgB = 0;         bgG = 255;     elif(variance > 0):             # too hot - no blue
        bgB = 0;
        bgR = adj;                  # red and green slide equally with Adj
        bgG = 255 - adj;
```